# Может ли внутренний класс быть наследником какого-либо другого класса?

Tags: java

Может ли внутренний класс быть наследником какого-либо другого класса?

Comment: а что мешает?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А почему бы и нет? Может.

```
public class First {
    public class Inner extends Second {

    }
}

public class Second {

}
```